# How to deal with deadlock happened because of range lock on sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server, database-deadlocks

**Table name** : Outbox

**Ways of insertion**:

1. We have service which does bulk inserts to Outbox table using async
   await and dapper(InsertAsync).
2. Also we have another process which has SP to inserts data to this Outbox table.

We observed a deadlock when data insertion happening to Outbox through both ways at same time.

As per my knowledge which I gathered by reading few article I think it is happening because of range lock.

Please help me to understand why this deadlock is happening?
And how we can resolve it?

Deadlock report:

```
   <event name="xml_deadlock_report" package="sqlserver" timestamp="2023-03-23T03:58:20.443Z">
       <data name="xml_report">
          <value>
             <deadlock>
                <victim-list>
                   <victimProcess id="process19fe2e3d848" />
                </victim-list>
                <process-list>
                   <process id="process19fe2e3d848" taskpriority="0" logused="212" waitresource="KEY: 8:72057622641901568 (586b65d87b07)" waittime="3179" ownerId="38640301269" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2023-03-22T22:58:16.997" XDES="0x1a41d5d0420" lockMode="X" schedulerid="5" kpid="9692" status="suspended" spid="308" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2023-03-22T22:58:17.247" lastbatchcompleted="2023-03-22T22:58:17.230" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.230" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="FNCCIWEBGOLFG01" hostpid="5004" loginname="FNC\qaconnect" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="38640301269" currentdb="8" currentdbname="usbls" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
                      <executionStack>
                         <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="862" stmtend="1954" sqlhandle="0x020000005aff830da8b435a8c36426baba4cab026fe256c30000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown</frame>
                         <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown</frame>
                      </executionStack>
                      <inputbuf>(@p21 bigint,@p0 uniqueidentifier,@p1 datetime2(7),@p2 datetime2(7),@p3 nvarchar(4000),@p23 nvarchar(4000),@p4 nvarchar(4000),@p5 uniqueidentifier,@p6 nvarchar(4000),@p7 datetime2(7),@p8 datetime2(7),@p9 datetime2(7),@p10 datetime2(7),@p11 nvarchar(4000),@p12 nvarchar(max) ,@p13 datetime2(7),@p14 datetime2(7),@p15 int,@p16 datetime2(7),@p17 datetime2(7),@p18 nvarchar(4000),@p19 bigint,@p20 tinyint,@p22 tinyint)SET NOCOUNT ON; UPDATE [outbox] SET [correlationId] = @p0, [createDate] = @p1, [createDateUtc] = @p2, [displayStatus] = @p3, [EntityId] = @p4, [eventId] = @p5, [eventName] = @p6, [LastChangedDate] = @p7, [LastChangedDateUtc] = @p8, [LastRetryDate] = @p9, [LastRetryDateUtc] = @p10, [note] = @p11, [payload] = @p12, [publishedDate] = @p13, [publishedDateUtc] = @p14, [RetriesCount] = @p15, [retryDate] = @p16, [retryDateUtc] = @p17, [SequenceGroup] = @p18, [SequenceNumber] = @p19, [status] = @p20 WHERE [id] = @p21 AND [displayStatus] IS NULL AND [status] = @p22; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;</inputbuf>
                   </process>
                   <process id="process1b91d74d088" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="3260" schedulerid="7" kpid="3476" status="suspended" spid="271" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2023-03-22T22:58:16.830" lastbatchcompleted="2023-03-22T22:58:16.840" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.840" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="FNCCIWEBGOLFG01" hostpid="20576" loginname="FNC\qaconnect" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="38640300510" currentdb="8" currentdbname="usbls" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                      <executionStack>
                         <frame procname="usbls.dbo.tr_outbox_sequence" line="25" stmtstart="1484" stmtend="1938" sqlhandle="0x03000800e8292c5345d6a7005caf000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">update outbox set outbox.sequenceNumber =0,                                outbox.sequenceGroup = (@newEventName + '_'+ @newEntityId)                              WHERE outbox.EventName + '_'+ isnull(outbox.EntityId,outbox.EventName) = (@newEventName + '_' + @newEntityId</frame>
                         <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="860" stmtend="2056" sqlhandle="0x02000000f0b753349d991b516eb59c608ac459f74c57d6f60000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown</frame>
                         <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown</frame>
                      </executionStack>
                      <inputbuf>(@CorrelationId uniqueidentifier,@CreateDate datetime,@CreateDateUtc datetime,@EntityId varchar(4000),@EventId uniqueidentifier,@EventName varchar(4000),@LastChangedDate datetime,@LastChangedDateUtc datetime,@LastRetryDate datetime,@LastRetryDateUtc datetime,@Note varchar(8000),@Payload varchar(max) ,@PublishedDate datetime,@PublishedDateUtc datetime,@RetriesCount int,@RetryDate datetime,@RetryDateUtc datetime,@Status tinyint)INSERT                                      INTO [Outbox] ([EventId],[CorrelationId],[EventName],[Payload],[CreateDateUtc],[CreateDate],[Status],[Note],[PublishedDateUtc],[PublishedDate],[RetriesCount],[RetryDateUtc],[RetryDate],[LastChangedDate],[LastChangedDateUtc],[LastRetryDate],[LastRetryDateUtc],[EntityId])                                      VALUES (@EventId,@CorrelationId,@EventName,@Payload,@CreateDateUtc,@CreateDate,@Status,@Note,@PublishedDateUtc,@PublishedDate,@RetriesCount,@RetryDateUtc,@RetryDate,@LastChangedDate,@LastChangedDateUtc,@LastRetryDate,@LastRetryDateUtc,@Ent</inputbuf>
                   </process>
                   <process id="process1b68ba2c4e8" taskpriority="0" logused="17344" waitresource="KEY: 8:72057622641901568 (586b65d87b07)" waittime="3113" ownerId="38640300510" transactionname="INSERT" lasttranstarted="2023-03-22T22:58:16.827" XDES="0x1b59bb6d980" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="2" kpid="2784" status="suspended" spid="271" sbid="0" ecid="1" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2023-03-22T22:58:16.830" lastbatchcompleted="2023-03-22T22:58:16.840" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.840" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="FNCCIWEBGOLFG01" hostpid="20576" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="38640300510" currentdb="8" currentdbname="usbls" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
                      <executionStack>
                         <frame procname="usbls.dbo.tr_outbox_sequence" line="25" stmtstart="1484" stmtend="1938" sqlhandle="0x03000800e8292c5345d6a7005caf000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">update outbox set outbox.sequenceNumber =0,                                outbox.sequenceGroup = (@newEventName + '_'+ @newEntityId)                              WHERE outbox.EventName + '_'+ isnull(outbox.EntityId,outbox.EventName) = (@newEventName + '_' + @newEntityId</frame>
                         <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="860" stmtend="2056" sqlhandle="0x02000000f0b753349d991b516eb59c608ac459f74c57d6f60000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown</frame>
                         <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown</frame>
                      </executionStack>
                      <inputbuf>(@CorrelationId uniqueidentifier,@CreateDate datetime,@CreateDateUtc datetime,@EntityId varchar(4000),@EventId uniqueidentifier,@EventName varchar(4000),@LastChangedDate datetime,@LastChangedDateUtc datetime,@LastRetryDate datetime,@LastRetryDateUtc datetime,@Note varchar(8000),@Payload varchar(max) ,@PublishedDate datetime,@PublishedDateUtc datetime,@RetriesCount int,@RetryDate datetime,@RetryDateUtc datetime,@Status tinyint)INSERT                                      INTO [Outbox] ([EventId],[CorrelationId],[EventName],[Payload],[CreateDateUtc],[CreateDate],[Status],[Note],[PublishedDateUtc],[PublishedDate],[RetriesCount],[RetryDateUtc],[RetryDate],[LastChangedDate],[LastChangedDateUtc],[LastRetryDate],[LastRetryDateUtc],[EntityId])                                      VALUES (@EventId,@CorrelationId,@EventName,@Payload,@CreateDateUtc,@CreateDate,@Status,@Note,@PublishedDateUtc,@PublishedDate,@RetriesCount,@RetryDateUtc,@RetryDate,@LastChangedDate,@LastChangedDateUtc,@LastRetryDate,@LastRetryDateUtc,@Ent</inputbuf>
                   </process>
                </process-list>
                <resource-list>
                   <keylock hobtid="72057622641901568" dbid="8" objectname="usbls.dbo.outbox" indexname="PK__tmp_ms_x__3213E83F6F4E22B6" id="lock1be62727e00" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057622641901568">
                      <owner-list>
                         <owner id="process1b91d74d088" mode="RangeS-S" />
                      </owner-list>
                      <waiter-list>
                         <waiter id="process19fe2e3d848" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
                      </waiter-list>
                   </keylock>
                   <exchangeEvent id="Pipe1a295aca290" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" waiterType="Coordinator" nodeId="2" tid="0" ownerActivity="sentData" waiterActivity="needMoreData" merging="true" spilling="false" waitingToClose="false">
                      <owner-list>
                         <owner id="process1b68ba2c4e8" />
                      </owner-list>
                      <waiter-list>
                         <waiter id="process1b91d74d088" />
                      </waiter-list>
                   </exchangeEvent>
                   <keylock hobtid="72057622641901568" dbid="8" objectname="usbls.dbo.outbox" indexname="PK__tmp_ms_x__3213E83F6F4E22B6" id="lock1be62727e00" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057622641901568">
                      <owner-list>
                         <owner id="process19fe2e3d848" mode="U" />
                         <owner id="process19fe2e3d848" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
                      </owner-list>
                      <waiter-list>
                         <waiter id="process1b68ba2c4e8" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait" />
                      </waiter-list>
                   </keylock>
                </resource-list>
             </deadlock>
          </value>
       </data>
    </event>
```

Comment: Why are you using serializable isolationlevel in some of these connections?

Comment: We are not applying on purpose I think it is getting applied by sql server may be because of some settings.
I am also looking for that settings.

Comment: Its a .NET default I think. It is set by the client anyway not the server